# XSLT, Add an attribute to the root node of the resultant xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am adding two xml files together using xslt, and then this resultant xml file should comply with a schema. I am able to add the two xml files together but then the result should have noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///osba.xsd" ass an attribute in the root element.

Here is my .xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" />
<xsl:variable name="with" select="'reception.xml'" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bd">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  <xsl:variable name="info" select="document($with)/reception/bd[title=current()/title]/." />
  <xsl:for-each select="$info/*">
    <xsl:if test="name()!='title'">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I want to add something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/*" >
  <xsl:attribute name="noNamespaceSchemaLocation"><![CDATA[file:///I:/IMY%20Project/XML%20Files/osba.xsd]]></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

I have not found any way to match if the current element is root, I was also thinking of maybe putting an xsl:if test="root" type of deal in the first xsl:template.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="noNamespaceSchemaLocation"
                namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">your-value</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```